# How can I get an Azure pipeline to preserve quotes in Maven execution?

Tags: maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have two goals: Maven release-prepare and Maven release.

I need to pass specific arguments to these goals, but they aren't getting parsed correctly because my double quotes are getting stripped.

Example:

```
  - task: Maven@3
    displayName: Performing Release Prepare
    inputs:
      mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
      mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m $(MAVEN_OPTS)'
      options: '-Darguments="-Darg1=true -Darg2=true"'
      javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
      jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
      publishJUnitResults: true
      testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
      goals: '--batch-mode release:prepare -DpushChanges=false -Dresume=false -Dtag=$(tagVersion) -DreleaseVersion=$(tagVersion) -DdevelopmentVersion=$(nextVersion)-SNAPSHOT'
```

The issue is the `-Darguments` flag. I can't seem to pass multiple values. If I pass it as-is like the example above, the quotes are stripped.

What I've tried:

Escaping quotes:

`'-Darguments=\"-Darg1=true -Darg2=true\"'`

`'-Darguments=\\"-Darg1=true -Darg2=true\\"'`

This still strips the quotes and leaves

`-Darguments=\-Darg1=true -Darg2=true\`

`-Darguments=\\-Darg1=true -Darg2=true\\`

I've also tried single quotes:

```
"-Darguments='-Darg1=true -Darg2=true'"
```

This *appears* to work as I see the single quotes in the pipeline logs, but the arguments aren't passed to the maven release plugin correctly. Some or all of the arguments are ignored. I'm unclear which ones, if any, are being accepted.

Passing multiple `-Darguments`

```
-Darguments=-Darg1=true -Darguments=-Darg2=true
```

Though this doesn't appear to be a valid way to pass multiple values.

So how can I add these arguments to my Azure pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to resolve this, so I worked around this with Maven profiles.

Something like this in my pom:

```
<profile>
  <id>release</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>performRelease</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <scmCommentPrefix>
              [maven-release-plugin] [skip ci]
            </scmCommentPrefix>             
            <allowTimestampedSnapshots>
              true
            </allowTimestampedSnapshots>
            <arguments>
              -Darg1=true -Darg2=true
            </arguments>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Then the pipeline just has this for the options value to trigger the profile:

```
options: '-DperformRelease=true'
```